# The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am getting this `error` while opening from `Report Manager URL` in SSRS.
Kindly help, I've got lot of reports there and I've to access those.

Comment: You have to provide more info. Are the report server services running? Have you tried to restart them? Are there any server configurations changes recently made, before the problem showed up

Comment: Services are running. I also had did the restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to check if SSRS service is running or it is under high load.

You can try to restart it.( *I think there was a SSRS bug when you changed the port it just stopped working. I think the restart will fix it*)

If it dosent help check this out ->[HERE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/17d3d563-d79b-4e54-bba9-5a64c247ce8d/how-to-fix-problem-503-service-unavailable-in-ssrs-?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because the user that was running the service was one that required a password to login, and we'd get frequent failures seemingly because of this in our automation test environment. Since I changed the Service Account in Report Service Configuration Manager to be the Virtual Service Account user, all has been well

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried to restart these two services ?
- SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
- SQL Server Reporting Services Web App (MSSQLSERVER)

Comment: Yes sabastien, I did. But still it is coming.

Answer (score 0):

What happened with me was a Session ID locked, I just kill it and worked fine.

Use **sp_who2** to get the transaction and Kill the locked one.

****KILL** ID**